# Como usar PDO em eval()

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como faço para usar PDO com a função eval(), visto que a maneira que uso está gerando erro.

```
$id = "return $bd->fetchAll();";
eval("$id");
eval("return $bd->fetchAll();");
```

ERROS:

```
 Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$fetchAll in 
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in
```

Comment: Para chamar métodos dentro de uma string, usa-se `{ }`. mude as duas linhas para: `$id = "return {$bd->fetchAll()};";`
`eval("return {$bd->fetchAll()};");`

Comment: Ainda continua gerando erro...

Comment: Tenta colocar \ nas variáveis. Ex: `eval("return \$bd->fetchAll();")`

Comment: Qual é o objetivo de usar o `eval()`?

Comment: Agora não gera erro mas também não retorna nenhuma dado, Empty... `eval("return \$conn->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);");`  sem eval retorna normal as querys...

Comment: obviamente que não retornaria dado algum pois apenas faz o retorno do objeto.. Aliás, viu a pergunta acima? Qual o motivo de uso do eval ?

Comment: documentação [evil ;)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Comment: Objetivo que é um class,  onde não irei ficar colocando é "fecht" faz isso, é fetchAll faz isso.. e assim por diante... daí para facilitar minha vida, eu passo o método por string...

Comment: Mas então ele retorna o objeto e dou um var_dump para verificar o que foi retornado...  Com eval vem vaziá, digitando o código retorna todos os dados...

Comment: Resolvido assim: `$id = "return \$conn->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS)";`
    `eval("\$id;");`

Comment: Independente dessa sua solução, tem 99,99% de chance de você estar fazendo um péssimo uso do `eval`. Se você explicar em detalhes o problema que está tentando resolver com isso (pode ser em outra pergunta), tenho certeza de que o pessoal vai te ajudar a achar uma solução melhor, sem `eval`.

Comment: Como eu disse acima, eu criei uma classe onde a pessoa fosse usar fetch ou fechAll ou outros métodos do PDO... Eu não gostaria de colocar um por um... ai no método que criei, digamos, escrevo: `$this->pega('fetch');`  daí ele adicionaria o método fetch,  `$this->pega('fetchAll');` daí usaria o médoto fetchall... existem vários e vários métodos no PDO, da ficaria ruim. Imagina que depois do fetch all, eu gostaria de contar o número de valores encontrados na busca...  com eval, eu poderia chamar mais métodos, sem ficar especificando em minha classe, Se fetch, faz isso, se FetchAll faz isso .

Comment: Daí eu colocaria direto o que eu quero: `$this->pega('return $conn->fecthAll(); if($conn->rowcount() >= 1)'){faz isso}` ... Eu poderia adicionar muito mais coisa ao meu código...

Answer (score 0):

## Atenção

Não sei o por quê de você querer fazer isso, mas já aviso de antemão que a utilização de `eval` quase sempre é considerado uma má prática.

Mas vou responder mesmo assim.

## Resposta

Para isso funcionar, você tem que escapar o sifrão `$` com uma barra `\`

Assim:

```
eval("return \$bd->fetchAll();");
```